# Is it possible to transpose a column of text values into a single row without duplicates, using a single Google Sheets formula?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, transpose

I have some data in one column that is dynamic, and being added to automatically:

```
Brand 1
Brand 2
Brand 3
Brand 4
Brand 5
Brand 2
Brand 2
```

Is it possible to transpose these, without duplicates to be headers in a row, ideally by just adding a formula in the Brand 1 cell?

E.g. `Brand 1, Brand 2, Brand 3, Brand 4, Brand 5`

Comment: You can't add a formula in the Brand 1 cell though, right? Has to be in a separate cell.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `transpose` and `unique`.

```
=transpose(unique(A1:A))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

add `FILTER` if you need to skip blanks

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>"")))
```

[image: 0]